# iPhone 6s activation

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to use LTE network to activate an iPhone.

How much data volume is needed to activate an iPhone?

Comment: While I can't give you a definite number, I would suspect that the data used is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

The activation process itself uses less than a Megabyte of data.

More data may be necessary once you sign in to an iCloud account with a lot of stored photos.